# Why is the image from my server not shown as source in my image tag?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Currently, I am trying to display an image that I provide from my API in my React app.
However, the image is not displayed in the frontend, all I see is a broken image icon.

The file is sent from the API as follows:

```tsx
router.get("/test", UserController.AuthenticationMiddleware, (req, res, next) => {

    res.sendFile(path.join(EnvironmentHelper.ImageStore, "test.jpg"));

});
```

The image tag in my frontend looks like this:

```html
<img src="http://localhost:3001/test"/>
```

But instead of my image, this is shown:

[image]

The network tab in chrome also shows 200 OK
[image]

Even after i open the img url in a new tab, it works:
[image]

Therefore, I wonder why this file can not be attracted, I can not think of any more reason here.
The image is obviously sent correctly, otherwise it would not work in the new tab.

I'm grateful for any help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by providing the 'crossOrigin' parameter on the image tag.